# google recaptcha curl 504 error on nginx server

Tags: php, curl, nginx

After submiting form with google recaptha 2 sometimes server return 504 error. In error log file

```
*28826 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 176.37.xxx.x, server: xxx.com, request: "POST /Adventure/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
```

I'm not sure, but I think this is slow response from the google via curl.

So help me find out why google return me response so slow and how can i increase the server timeout or solve my problem in anyway?
By the way i using yii2 and this recaptcha module https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget

yii log file

```
file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=xxxxxxxxremoteip=178.255.xxx.xxx): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget/ReCaptchaValidator.php:98
```

Comment: Provide your source so we can help.

Comment: there is no something special in source, all other forms without recaptcha works fine